# How to use Mod Rewrite correctly

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

since few days I'm wondering how mod rewrite is used correctly.

When I'm working on my site, should I already link everything like it's visible for the user

for exampel:

```
<a href="index.php?site=news"/> or <a href="news"/> ?
```

or should I use index.php?site=news and then just modify the URL with a [R] redirect?

Comment: Use the second (`<a href="news">`) in your HTML and use mod_rewrite to make the magic happen. The idea is to make the URLs easy for the users.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for the clarification. I really wasn't sure which path I should choose while developing the page.

Comment: A better way is to have a single rewrite rule, that passes all to a php router that handles routing parameter logic.